# Local Time to UTC in Java

Tags: java, android, date, datetime

I am trying to convert local time to UTC time in java. I have written the code:

```
    String datesToConvert = "31-12-2018 23:37:00";
    String dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss";

    SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
    sdf2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
    Date gmt = null;

    SimpleDateFormat sdfOutPutToSend = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
    sdfOutPutToSend.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

    try {
        gmt = sdf2.parse(datesToConvert);
        System.out.println("UTC FORMATTED DATE : " + sdfOutPutToSend.format(gmt));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The Output I am getting is :
UTC FORMATTED DATE : 2018-12-31T18:07:00.000Z

But I want it to be same date and time but changes in .000Z at last which shows the time difference.

Comment: You should avoid using the legacy `java.util.Date`, as it is not fit for purpose.  You should instead look at the `java.time` package for the appropriate classes for your use case.

Comment: What is the desired ouyput?

Comment: Desired Output: 2018-12-31T23:37:00.808Z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

Use modern *java.time* classes.

```
LocalDateTime
.parse( 
    "31-12-2018 23:37:00" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MM-uuuu HH:mm:ss" )
)
.atOffset(
    ZoneOffset.UTC 
)
.toString()
```

> 2018-12-31T23:37Z

## java.time

Use the modern *java.time* classes, not those terrible legacy classes such as `Date`.

Parse your input string as a `LocalDateTime` as it lacks any indicator of time zone or offset-from-UTC, and therefore does *not* represent a moment.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MM-uuuu HH:mm:ss" ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "31-12-2018 23:37:00" , f ) ;
```

You claim to know the time zone which was intended for this input string. If you are certain, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`, to determine an actual moment, a point on the timeline.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;
```

Your Question is not clear. But it appears you may be saying the input was intended to represent a moment in UTC. If so, apply `ZoneOffset.UTC` constant to get a `OffsetDateTime` object.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

> Desired Output: 2018-12-31T23:37:00.808Z

This is impossible, as your input string lacked the fractional second `.808`.

The ending you reported as a problem, `.000Z` would be correct as the zeros mean there is no fractional second. The `Z` on the end means UTC (an offset-from-UTC of zero), is short for `+00:00`, and is pronounced `Zulu`.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Great..  It helps