# Trying to find out how to convert local time into universal time (java), all the answers I found don't seem to work for me

Tags: j#

I have this (the code), and the answer (the hour) should be 11.00
The problem is that the answers I am getting are completely wrong;
(wed april 10 13:09:04 ), todays date ...
Also, i guess it needs the lat and long as well, how must I parse this ?

```
String dateString = 26 + "-" + 4 + "-" + 1926 + "  " + 5 + ":00:00 " ;
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat( dateString );
f.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
System.out.println( (new Date()) );
String dd = f.format(new Date());
System.out.println( "    " ) ;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Local Time to UTC in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53029858/local-time-to-utc-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

I've got ;

```
String d = LocalDateTime
        .parse(
                "26-04-1926 05:00:00",
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MM-uuuu HH:mm:ss" )
        )
        .atOffset(
                ZoneOffset.UTC
        )
        .toString();

System.out.println( d ) ;
```

But the output is '1926-04-26T05:00Z'
while the hour should be 11:00

Where did I went wrong?
Also, can I get the output (the hour) as an int?