# java 8 LocalTime to LocalTime UTC

Tags: java, java-8

I have a LocalTime instance created by parsing as below

Below time("01:00:00") is in ET,

```
LocalTime time1 = LocalTime.parse("01:00:00");
```

Now I want to convert this time1 to UTC LocalTime, NOT LocalDateTime or LocalDate. How to use that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Local Time to UTC in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53029858/local-time-to-utc-in-java)

Comment: "Below time is in ET" No it's not. `LocalTime`s are not in a timezone. `ZonedDateTime`s are. It only makes sense to convert between timezones if you also have a date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now I want to convert this time1 to UTC LocalTime

LocalTime fundamentally means 'timezone-less', and UTC is a timezone.

That is like saying: "I want to convert this shape into a circle.. but with corners'. If you stick a corner in a circle it is no longer a circle. If you want some LocalTime, 'but in UTC', it is no longer a LocalTime.

```
OffsetTime ot = LocalTime.parse("01:00:00").atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

will get you there. From there you can e.g. invoke `.atDate(someLocalDate)` to get an `OffsetDateTime` object out.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Yes, I converted to offsetdatetime with utc and later converted to local time to get the utc hours. This is helpful.